# How can I avoid unbound version constraints in composer?

Tags: symfony, error-handling, composer-php

I made a composer diagnose and I get the Warning:

> WARNING require.symfony/serializer-pack : unbound version constraints
>   (*) should be avoided require.symfony/webpack-encore-pack : unbound
>   version constraints (*) should be avoided

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-are-unbound-version-constraints-a-bad-idea.md

Just define a suitable version after the required package like

```
symfony/serializer-pack:^4.0
```

which will prevent choosing ANY (maybe bc breaking) version.